# Sklearn Naive Bayes GaussianNB from .csv

Tags: python, scikit-learn, valueerror, naivebayes

I'm having a problem with sklearn.
When I train it with ".fit()" it shows me the ValueError "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Casado'"
This is my code:
"""

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import pandas as pd



# 1. Create Naive Bayes classifier:
gaunb = GaussianNB()

# 2. Create dataset:
dataset = pd.read_csv("archivos_de_datos/Datos_Historicos_Clientes.csv")
X_train = dataset.drop(["Compra"], axis=1) #Here I removed the last column "Compra"
Y_train = dataset["Compra"] #This one only consists of that column "Compra"
print("X_train: ","\n", X_train)
print("Y_train: ","\n", Y_train)
dataset2 = pd.read_csv("archivos_de_datos/Nuevos_Clientes.csv")
X_test = dataset2.drop("Compra", axis=1)

print("X_test: ","\n", X_test)

# 3. Train classifier with dataset:
gaunb = gaunb.fit(X_train, Y_train) #Here shows "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Casado'"


# 4. Predict using classifier:
prediction = gaunb.predict(X_test)

print("PREDICTION: ",prediction)
"""
```

And the dataset I'm using is an .csv file that looks like this (but with more rows):

```
IdCliente,EstadoCivil,Profesion,Universitario,TieneVehiculo,Compra
1,Casado,Empresario,Si,No,No
2,Casado,Empresario,Si,Si,No
3,Soltero,Empresario,Si,No,Si
```

I'm trying to train it to determine (with a test dataset) whether the last column would be a Yes or No (Si or No)

I appreciate your help, I'm obviously new at this and I don't understand what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Perhaps the Naive Bayes Classifier is looking for numeric features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use onehotencoder to, like Lavin mentioned, make the yes or no a numerical value. A model such as this can't process categorical data.

Onehotencoder is used to handle binary data such as yes/no, male/female, while label encoder is used for categorical data with more than 2 values, ei, country names.

It will look something like this, however, you'll have to do this with all categorical data, not just your y column, and use label encoder for columns that are not binary ( more than 2 variables - for example, perhaps Estadio Civil)

Also I would suggest removing any dependent variables that don't contribute to your model, for instant client ID sounds like it may not add any value in determining your dependent variable. This is context specific, but something to keep in mind.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [Insert column number for your df])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

For the docs:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

More info:
[https://contactsunny.medium.com/label-encoder-vs-one-hot-encoder-in-machine-learning-3fc273365621#:~:text=What%20one%20hot%20encoding%20does,which%20column%20has%20what%20value.&text=So%2C%20that's%20the%20difference%20between%20Label%20Encoding%20and%20One%20Hot%20Encoding](https://contactsunny.medium.com/label-encoder-vs-one-hot-encoder-in-machine-learning-3fc273365621#:%7E:text=What%20one%20hot%20encoding%20does,which%20column%20has%20what%20value.&text=So%2C%20that%27s%20the%20difference%20between%20Label%20Encoding%20and%20One%20Hot%20Encoding).

Comment: Thanks! I've been told that, as Naive Bayes is a classifier, it allowed categorical data.
But either I'm missing sth or it definitely doesn't allow it..
BTW, I tried your way and it worked.. The only problem might be decoding the result.
But, since the answer in this case is binary, Yes or No, is pretty simple, 1 for Yes, 0 for No.
I used LabelEncoder for all of them just to try it out and it worked just fine.

Thanks!